# Visual Studio Code starting from command line batch prints out "update#setState" every hour

Tags: command-line, visual-studio-code

my Batch looks like this

```
@Start "VisualStudioCode" "C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" %*
```

in the command windows i got every hour a message:

```
[main 12:14:41] update#setState idle
[main 13:14:39] update#setState checking for updates
[main 13:14:40] update#setState idle
[main 14:14:39] update#setState checking for updates
[main 14:14:43] update#setState idle
[main 15:14:39] update#setState checking for updates
[main 15:14:41] update#setState idle
[main 16:14:39] update#setState checking for updates
[main 16:14:40] update#setState idle
[main 17:14:39] update#setState checking for updates
[main 17:14:41] update#setState idle
```

how can i supress these messages?

Answer (score 20):

Try running "C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin\Code.cmd" instead, as this is the CLI version.  Code.exe is the electron app that should not be in the path.

Comment: that works but there is one other problem with cli version.  
    i set this in user settings:  
    `    "files.autoGuessEncoding": false,  
        "[bat]": {  
         "files.encoding": "cp850",  
         "editor.tabSize": 3,  
         "editor.detectIndentation": false  
        },`  
    when vsc is not running and i start it via cli and param "my.bat" the encoding goes to `UTF-8`  
    when vsc is running all *.bat files are opend with `cp850`

Answer (score 16):

The solution for me was to remove:

```
D:\Users\<me>\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\
```

from my path and add:

```
D:\Users\<me>\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin
```

Now when I type'code' it launches code.cmd, not code.exe. (My paths are for the per-user version. Adjust for system-wide version as necessary)

Comment: Same for me. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I had weird WSL output caused by an alias to the wrong path you pointed out. I updated my .bashrc to remove the "code" alias and instead added the correct code directory to my PATH: export PATH="$PATH:/mnt/c/Users/<me>/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin"

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. In my case what worked was to open all applications in "administrator" mode and it worked perfectly. Both the VS Code and also the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

i ended here:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set VSCODE_DEV=
set ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE=1
call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" "C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\cli.js" -n
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 2 > nul
call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" "C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\cli.js" %*
endlocal
```

Answer (score 0):

I always start VS Code from the Taskbar, but still get these messages in my Command Prompt window -- and the times make no sense for my location or for GMT.

Solution:

Go to File->Preferences->Online Services Settings.
Look for Update Mode and expand it.  Select anything except default (which is 'automatic').  I selected 'start' (which I think used to be the default). Changing this requires you to restart VS Code, after which you should be free of the periodic checks and messages.  You can still check for updates manually as well.

Answer (score 0):

Move D:\Users<me>\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin
to higher than python310/bin in path setting.